# How does the size of an n-ball (of a graph) scale as a function of n for various centers of the ball

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected locally finite graph with countably infinitely many vertices. Consider $B_n(v)$, the ball of radius $n$ centerd at vertex $v\in G$, that is, the set of all vertices that are a distance $n$ or less to $v$. I suspect that the way that the ball grows as $n$ increases should be independent of $v$. To be more precise, I suspect that if the function $f_v(n) := |B_n(v)| \in O(g(n))$, then so must $f_w(n) \in O(g(n))$ for any $w\in G$.

My reason for suspecting this is that, because the graph $G$ is assumed to be connected, we have a finite path between any two vertices $v$ and $w$. As $n$ grows, the balls of radius $n$ will overlap evermore, and thus the size of the balls should be similar.

I would like a proof/counter example of this claim, and if applicable, the name of the theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two vertices $v,w$ are at distance $d$, then $f_v(n) \ge f_w(n-d)$ and $f_w(n) \ge f_v(n-d)$. Whether this gets us what we want depends on how quickly these functions grow: can we say that $f_v(n) = O(f_v(n-d))$? That's true when the growth rate is at most exponential, which covers all graphs you *typically* encounter.

However, it's possible to write down functions that don't have this behavior. For example, if $f_v(n)$ grows like $2^{n^2}$, then it is not even true that $2^{n^2} = O(2^{(n-1)^2})$; there is a factor of $2^{2n-1}$ difference.

It's also possible to draw locally finite graphs where $f_v(n)$ will have this growth rate. Take a half-infinite path $v_1, v_2, v_3, \dots$ and let $w = v_1$ and $v = v_2$. Right now, we have $$f_v(n) = \begin{cases}1 & n=0 \\ n+2 & n \ge 1\end{cases}$$
But suppose we add $\ell_i$ leaves to $v_i$ for every $i \ge 3$. Then we will have $$
   f_v(n) = \begin{cases}1 & n=0 \\ 3 & n=1 \\ (n + 2) + \ell_3 + \dots + \ell_{n+1} & n\ge 2\end{cases}
$$
and it is easy to choose $\ell_3, \ell_4, \dots$ so that for all $n \ge 2$, $f_v(n) = 2^{n^2}$.

In this example, $f_w(n)$ will lag behind: its growth rate will be "merely" $O(2^{(n-1)^2})$. Even though it is always just one step behind $v$, that one step makes all the difference.